# MacPro - D700 Multi-Display Not Working When Using Windows 10

Tags: display, bootcamp, windows, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro with dual D700 graphics cards connected to 3x4K displays, and I've used Bootcamp to install Windows 10.

When running MacOS Catalina, all of the displays work fine.

When running Windows 10, the displays worked at first, but once Windows had updated the drivers and installed the FirePro software, only the primary display works. Windows detects the other displays, but they display a message (from the display itself) suggesting that they're not receiving signal and going into stand-by.

[image]

The screenshot above demonstrates that as far as Windows is concerned, I have three displays connected, however only the centre screen is actually displaying an image - the other two displays are in stand-by, and I can't seem to get a signal.

Is this a common problem? Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: I believe your issue is allowing FirePro drivers to be updated in Windows. You will probably need to stick to the drivers that come with Bootcamp and wait for Apple to give you updated drivers.

Comment: @DaveNelson Uninstalling the Windows drivers and installing the latest Bootcamp ones actually made it worse...none of the displays are working now. And it won't even let me get to the boot selection screen so I can get back into MacOS :-(

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work for you. After a lot of searching I haven't found any good ideas how to fix your issue.